# How to sort a team data in alphabet order

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I've a table like this: `Dim Classifica_Table() As Team_Data`

I want to order the table in alphabet mode, in particular, this table contains all team of a championship grabbed by webpage.

This value are inserted in a Combobox:

```
For Each Team As Team_Data In Classifica_Table
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Team.Name) 'Populate Combo Boxes with team names
    Next
```

but the order isn't good for me, so I want sort in alphabet.
How can I do this? I tried with `Classifica_Table.Sort()` but seems doesn't working, the compiler tells me: that nothing Sort() accept this argument number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [IEnumerable extension OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
For Each Team As Team_Data In Classifica_Table.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name)
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(Team.Name) 
Next
```